# Putting an ExpandableListView into a fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I'm making my first Android application, a project for my university.
Now, I followed [this guide](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/expandablelistview.php#Dynamic%20ExpandableListView%20Creation%20in%20Android) to create an expandable list, but now I want to have it in it's own fragment so that it looks like more or less.

[image] 
Can anyone help me with that? I'm quite inexperienced with Android tbh, so I appreciate any help I can get!

Snippet from the guide:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

/* ******************** Start Group  ********************* */
Map<String, String> curgroupMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
groupData.add(curgroupMap1);
curgroupMap1.put("parent", "Master 1");

List<Map<String,String>> children1 =new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
/* *** ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children1.add(curChildMap1);
curChildMap1.put("child", "Bank");

/* *** ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children1.add(curChildMap2);
curChildMap2.put("child", "Executive");

/* *** ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children1.add(curChildMap3);
curChildMap3.put("child", "Customer");

/* ***ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children1.add(curChildMap4);
curChildMap4.put("child", "State");

/* ***ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children1.add(curChildMap5);
curChildMap5.put("child", "City");

childData.add(children1);

/* *************************End Group **************************/

/* ******************** Start Group  ********************* */
Map<String, String> curgroupMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
groupData.add(curgroupMap2);
curgroupMap2.put("parent", "Master 2");
List<Map<String,String>> children2 =new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

/* *** ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap6 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children2.add(curChildMap6);
curChildMap6.put("child", "Android");

/* *** ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap7 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children2.add(curChildMap7);
curChildMap7.put("child", "iPhone");

/* *** ChildData ***/
Map<String, String> curChildMap8 = new HashMap<String, String>();
children2.add(curChildMap8);
curChildMap8.put("child", "Windows");

childData.add(children2);

/* *************************End Group **************************/


 mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { "parent" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {"child"},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }
            );
 setListAdapter(mAdapter);

 expand = getExpandableListView();

 expand.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (groupPosition)
        {
        case 0 :
            switch(childPosition)
            {
            case 0 :
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bank",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Executive",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Customer",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3 :
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "State",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4 :
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "City",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            switch(childPosition)
            {
            case 0 :
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Android",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "iPhone",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Windows",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                break;
            }
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: why do you think that *you need a fragment*?? it's just a design that you need to follow..

Comment: Well, I'd really like to do it like this, as I already have a mockup of project and like to stick to the rough design. If there's an easier way, let me know!

Comment: There is no NEED to change the java code.. **All you require is an XML to design such layout.**

Comment: Alrighty, than I'll take a look into that I guess? Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

well, if you have done this in activity then you don't have to do anymore work than, load the fragment and do the same thing.

1. instantiate your views in onCreateView() in fragment. You should not assume that your views are actually available to make any changes. UI changes should be done in OnActivityCreated().
2. load your expandable listview in onActivityCreated() of that fragment.

code will be quite the same only that you would be referring to views like this

Eg: Listview listview = (Listview)getActivity().findViewbyID(R.id.listview); in your onCreateview()